# Moving information from one table to another and then deleting that data from its origin

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, sql-delete

I'm making a roster creation tool and one part of the tool is to remove the graduated students from the roster pool and put them into another table called CompletedArchive. After they are copied to the other table I want them to be deleted from the RosterPool table.

```
INSERT INTO CompletedArchive ( Rate, FullName, Last4, Graduated )
SELECT RosterPool.Rate, RosterPool.FullName, RosterPool.Last4, RosterPool.Graduated
FROM RosterPool
WHERE ((RosterPool.Graduated)="Yes");
```

I cannot find out where to add the DELETE statement and not get an error. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have to run two different commands here:

```
INSERT INTO CompletedArchive ( Rate, FullName, Last4, Graduated )
SELECT RosterPool.Rate, RosterPool.FullName, RosterPool.Last4, RosterPool.Graduated
FROM RosterPool
WHERE ((RosterPool.Graduated)="Yes");
```

and then

```
DELETE FROM RosterPool
WHERE ((RosterPool.Graduated)="Yes");
```

Also, make sure you run the two commands within the same transaction. That way you will have the chance to rollback if anything goes wrong.

Comment: So I should just create a macro that will run one and then the other? The reason I ask is because I will not be running the program. I am jsut creating it.

Comment: Wait, macro. Are you using MySQL or is it something else?

Comment: You could also define an `on delete` trigger which would insert the records into the archive table (if the condition was met).  Otherwise, I recommend deleting from `RosterPool` only when some unique id is also present in `CompletedArchive` (or you risk deleting a row that isn't yet present in the archive - this is possible even inside a transaction).